# JS array with key in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to add some value to some "array" but I want that if for example this array has already the value which I want to insert to get some exception,which object or "special array" I can use in java script in node

Comment: You have some code to share with us?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a helper function that runs an `indexOf` check and throws the error manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```js
var dataStore = {
  _dataStore: {},
  add: function(key, data) {
    if (this._dataStore[key]) {
      throw new Error('already exist');
    }
    this._dataStore[key] = data;
  },
  get: function(key) {
    return this._dataStore[key];
  }
};
//usage
dataStore.add('some-key', 'test');
//will throw exception
//dataStore.add('some-key', 'test');

alert(dataStore.get('some-key'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use objects. Also good library to use for this kind of stuff is [lodash](https://lodash.com/).